# read NASADEM .slope file into R and change format to .tif file

Tags: r, raster, tiff, gdal, rgdal

I downloaded some tiles using [NASA EARTHDATA](https://search.earthdata.nasa.gov/search) for the [NASADEM Slope and Curvation Global 1 arc second V001](https://search.earthdata.nasa.gov/search/granules?p=C1546314671-LPDAAC_ECS&pg%5B0%5D%5Bv%5D=f&pg%5B0%5D%5Bgsk%5D=-start_date&q=SRTM%20aspect&sb%5B0%5D=35.3%2C31.2%2C46.5%2C37.6&tl=1641232213!3!!&m=35.155970850269405!29.2762605906558!5!1!0!0%2C2) data set. When I extracted the files, I saw the filenames followed the pattern: "TileLocation.Variable". For example, a tile with slope data located on the eastern Mediteranian is called: "n36e035.slope". I was surprised the file extension was ".slope" and not ".tif".

When I tried reading the file into R with `r <- raster::raster("Filepath/n36e035.slope")` I get an error, because the file structure is not a tif or geotiff. I want to read multiple tiles for each variable (slope, curvature, etc.), merge, crop to my study area, then write out the combined raster to my local device as a .tif file. That way the DEM file format and data structure will match the other rasters I have.

My preferred language is R, but if there's another open-source way to change the file format from this NASA-specific extension to a .tif then I can use that. I tried looking online, but all the tutorials used Google Earth Engine or Arc and didn't allow me to save the combined .tif files locally.

You can download the n36e35 zip [here](https://e4ftl01.cr.usgs.gov//DP132/MEASURES/NASADEM_SC.001/2000.02.11/NASADEM_SC_n36e035.zip) and the n35e35 zip [here](https://e4ftl01.cr.usgs.gov//DP132/MEASURES/NASADEM_SC.001/2000.02.11/NASADEM_SC_n35e035.zip). You may need to log-in to NASA EARTHDATA to view and download the DEM tiles. The overview is [here](https://cmr.earthdata.nasa.gov/search/concepts/C1546314671-LPDAAC_ECS.html) and the user guide is available [here](https://lpdaac.usgs.gov/documents/592/NASADEM_User_Guide_V1.pdf), but the user guide is more about how the data set was made, not how to read it in or change the data format. One strange note is that the DEM this data set is based off of has an .hgt file extension, which I can easily read into R with the `raster::raster` function.

Comment: You might have better luck on [gis.se], since people there probably have more experience with these file types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regrettably, NASA does not provide header files so you need to create them yourself.

To help with that, I added a function `makeVRT` to the `terra version 1.5-9`. That is currently the development version, you can install it with `install.packages('terra', repos='https://rspatial.r-universe.dev')`. I use that function in `demhdr` below (after looking at this [github repo](https://github.com/dshean/nasadem/blob/master/srtm_hdr.sh) by David Shean) that sets the specific parameters for these files. Parameters are also give [here](https://lpdaac.usgs.gov/products/nasadem_scv001/) but note that on that page the datatype for SWB is incorrectly given as 8-bit signed integer, whereas it should be 8-bit unsigned integer.

```
demhdr <- function(filename, ...) {
    f <- basename(filename)
    stopifnot(tools::file_ext(f) != "vrt")
    sign <- ifelse(substr(f, 1, 1) == "n", 1, -1)
    lat <- sign * as.numeric(substr(f, 2, 3))
    sign <- ifelse(substr(f, 4, 4) == "e", 1, -1)
    lon <- sign * as.numeric(substr(f, 5, 7))
    if (grepl("aspect", f) || grepl("slope", f)) {
        datatype <- "INT2U"
    } else if (grepl("swb", f)) {
        datatype <- "INT1U"
    } else {
        datatype <- "FLT4S"
    }
    name <- unlist(strsplit(f, "\\."))[2]
    terra::makeVRT(filename, 3601, 3601, 1, xmin=lon, ymin=lat, xres=1/3600,
           lyrnms=name, datatype=datatype, byteorder="MSB", ...) 
}
```

For a folder with these files that do not end on ".vrt":

```
ff <- grep(list.files("."), pattern="\\.vrt$", invert=TRUE, value=TRUE)
ff
#[1] "n37e037.aspect" "n37e037.planc"  "n37e037.profc"  "n37e037.slope" 
#[5] "n37e037.swb"
```

You can use the `demhdr` function like this:

```
fvrt <- sapply(ff, demhdr, USE.NAMES=FALSE)
fvrt
#"n37e037.aspect.vrt"  "n37e037.planc.vrt"  "n37e037.profc.vrt" 
# "n37e037.slope.vrt"    "n37e037.swb.vrt"
```

And then, with files for a single tile, you can do

```
library(terra)
r <- rast(fvrt)
r
#class       : SpatRaster 
#dimensions  : 3601, 3601, 5  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 0.0002777778, 0.0002777778  (x, y)
#extent      : 36.99986, 38.00014, 36.99986, 38.00014  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
#sources     : n37e037.aspect.vrt  
#              n37e037.planc.vrt  
#              n37e037.profc.vrt  
#              ... and 2 more source(s)
#names       : aspect, planc, profc, slope, swb
```

Note the very unfortunate georeferencing of NASA SRTM data. The data would have lined up with other lon/lat raster data, and would have been much more usable if the extent *would have been* `37.0, 38.0, 37.0, 38.0` and the number of rows and columns *would have been* 3600. But that is not the case.

```
plot(r)
```

[image]

This tile did not seem to have no data values; in other tiles you may need to set it with the `NAflag` argument in `makeVRT` or by using `NAflag(x) <-` on single layer `SpatRaster`

For aspect, it looks like you could use `scale=0.01` to get values between 0 and 360 degrees)

To merge many tiles for say aspect, you should be able to do something like

```
fasp <- grep("aspect", fvrt, value=TRUE)
x <- src(lapply(fasp, rast))
m <- merge(x)
```

or make a new VRT file that combines the tiles, like this

```
vrt(fasp, "aspect.vrt")
m <- rast("aspect.vrt")
```

To read the files with `raster`

```
library(raster)
s <- stack(fvrt)
```

Comment: Also, I recognized your surname, so I did a quick Google Scholar search. I read some of your SDM pubs for my Ecological Niche Modeling class. Thank-you for writing great papers (and, more recently, thank-you for answering my NASA DEM questions)!

Comment: I deleted my old comment (which was a follow-up question) because your update already answered the question and cleared up my confusion. The code runs now. Thank you! Hopefully I can adjust the aspect values, handle NAs, merge, and crop my rasters flawlessly. Realistically I'll be digging through the terra and raster packages tonight for help with my inevitable bugs.